# odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect

Tags: php, ubuntu, odbc, sybase, freetds

I am getting error

> odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name
>   not found, and no default driver specified, SQL state IM002 in
>   SQLConnect for Linux server

while executing following command to connect with sybase from PHP.

```
$db = ADONewConnection('odbc');

$DSN = 'UID=username;PWD=password;EngineName=dbServiceName;AutoStop=No;Integrated=No;Debug=No;DisableMultiRowFetch=No;CommLinks=SharedMemory,TCPIP{};Compress=No;Driver={Adaptive Server Anywhere 9.0}';


$db->Connect($DSN );
```

I have **installed ODBC drivers with FreeTDS** to connect Sybase database with PHP code with following commands

- sudo apt-get install unixodbc
- sudo apt-get install tdsodbc
- sudo apt-get install freetds-bin tdsodbc

**/etc/odbc.ini** file

- Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
- Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
- Server = server_name
- Port = port_number
- Database = dbname
- Username = dbusername
- Password = dbpassword

**freetds.conf** file

```
[sybase]
    host=
    port=
    Tds version=
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using FreeTDS, you need to specify the driver from `odbcinst.ini`, which is normally FreeTDS. Try:

```
$DSN = 'UID=username;PWD=password;EngineName=dbServiceName;AutoStop=No;Integrated=No;Debug=No;DisableMultiRowFetch=No;CommLinks=SharedMemory,TCPIP{};Compress=No;Driver={FreeTDS}';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion. I have tried to connect database server using terminal and it is working fine but I am getting same error in php connection? I have tried in terminal "tsql -S SYBASE -U <username> -P <password>"